Can't send credentials through fetch() on client-side
I can't send cookies via fetch() request with credentials: 'include' on client-side.

My Nest.js application sent me cookies with Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None flags for cross-domain requests. Cookies installed in the browser:


I have following configuration for CORS in my Nest.js application:


app.enableCors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: 'https://localhost:3000',
      methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
      allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type',
    });


I call this request via fetch() method on client-side of Next.js application

fetch('https://example.com/api_v1/courses', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(generalInfo),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })


Request and response headers between Next.js and Nest.js apps look like that:

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 18 May 2024 15:44:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 107
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
ETag: W/"6b-9t5M7Hn+uoxF7tGekSbtmY3SS/E"

POST /api_v1/courses HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 98
Content-Type: application/json
Host: mentorium.su
Origin: https://localhost:3000
Referer: https://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"

But browser still can't include Cookie header in request.
P.S.
Chrome DevTools is also silent and does not reject cookies
Browser fetch() should include Cookie in request headers on client-side
